# How to handle new browser pop up after clicking a js button in Watir?

Tags: ruby, browser, watir

I am trying to using watir in ruby, I am able open a browser,
enter some values to a username/password form, but then I press enter, then I click the submit button (actually it is pressing an enter, it is easiler to code), it would pop up a new browser windows for our application, then I found I have no control to the new browser. What can I do?

In addition to my problem, the new browser window got no menubar, no toolbar, no navigation bar, thus I cannot open the IE developer toolbar to find the name of the element in the webpage in the new browser.

By the way, my app can only support IE.

---

I tried the attach method, but it does work:

C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb:302:

in `attach_browser_window': Unable to locate a window with title of (?-mix:New browser title) (Watir::Exception::NoMatchingWindowFoundException)

```
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb
```

:150:in `_attach_init'

```
    from C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/watir-1.8.1/lib/watir/ie-class.rb
```

:144:in `attach'
        from test1.rb:36

Comment: 1) Show Us Your Watir Code where you are trying the attach.  Edit the posting above to add in the code, I think I know what you are doing wrong but can't be sure till I see the code. 
2) Did you try using f12 to open the dev toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach method is able to handle new window. 
http://rdoc.info/gems/watir/1.8.1/Watir/IE.attach

for example

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.text_field(:id,'username').set 'username')
browser.button(:index,1).click
# popped up the new window
popup = Watir::Browser.attach(:title,'Foobar')
```

If you will use only the popped up window, you can overwrite browser variable instead.

Comment: it doesn't work.......I tried like this:
ie2 = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /New browser title/)
ie2.close
the new browser didn't close, I assume it is not working.
i've also tried Watir::IE, same result

Comment: If you know the browser title exactly, there's no reason to use a regex to match it, just put the title in quotes.

Comment: Hmmm.. it looks like you couldn't detect the window by title. If you know the URL you want to attach, try :url attribute. popup = Watir::Browser.attach(:url,/url/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to authenticate like so:

examplehost.com/authentication?user=foo&password=bar

You could also try to remove "target" attribute (which is probably equal to "_blank") of that authentication form ( i'm pretty much sure you should be able to achive this with watir )

EDIT:

Also, there's this option:

```
ie2 = Watir::IE.attach(:title, ‘New Ie window, opened upon form submit’)
```

it can also attach by :url instead of :title

Comment: Can you explain more of how to "remove target attribute"? If I remove the target attribute, it would open in the same windows?

Comment: Disclaimer: the button is actually a <IMG> node, with a onClick event.

Answer (score 0):

ok, there's  possibly this solution that might work:

```
b = Watir::Browser.start "http://yourpage"

b.execute_script("document.getElementById('your-image-id').onClick = function() {}")
```

so, the idea is to get that image and overwrite it's onclick event