# watir ruby Follow link redirection and get final url

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Hello I see there is way to handle redirect with ruby, but I was thinking aybe there is the way to do it with watir and then it will be same browser and coockie etc.

So if anyon can give me example how to follow url.

Let's write exapmle:

This is link www. ly.by/ldkfjfjgii
in watir I already have destination link
and I could say

```
link = b.frame(:id => 'main_top_right').link(:index => 0).click
```

so is there a way to catch redirected url (final destination url), where it lands
example it could land on http:// somesite. com/jdkdjfk.

I want that final url after redirect with watir, I hope I was clear.
tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking on any link, you can get the current URL of the page by using

```
browser.url
```

in case clicking URL opening the link in new window/tab, you can use

```
browser.windows.last.use do
browser.url
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the link, the .url method from the Watir::Browser class can obtain the URL.

This is a link to the rdoc: http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/0.6.0/Watir/Browser#url-instance_method

Example:

```
b.frame(:id => 'main_top_right').link(:index => 0).click  
url_after_click = b.url
```

Comment: Please don't just provide "code-only" answers. Explain the "why" not just the "what".

Comment: What if the link opens new window how to follow it. Target - blank

Comment: Then you'd need to attach to the new browser window.  This might get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5630084/how-to-handle-new-browser-pop-up-after-clicking-a-js-button-in-watir